# Applying Temporal Derivatives on Audio and Video

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, audio, video, neural-network

I have a video dataset of people speaking out digit numbers from 0-9 randomly. My goal is train a neural network on audio/visual patterns of speech.

To achieve my goal I first had to dissect this video into small little videos where each video contains a person speaking exactly one digit at a time.

Once I had my individual videos, I extracted exactly 10 fps for each second in the video and ended up with sequential images of the video. I did this using the famous command line tool ffmpeg.

I then used opencv to extract the region of interest (ROI), in this case the mouth. I later did some research and found out that for me to model the dynamic speech information I had to apply what is called a "Temporal Derivative" on these images.

Moreover, during my extraction of images from the video I have also extracted audio information in the form of raw spectrograms. I also intend to do Temporal Derivation on the spectrogram as well to preserve the dynamic change of frequency as time progresses.

I have read about Temporal/Time Derivatives and found that simply it is the derivative of a function as time changes.

I wonder how would I apply this on my images and spectrograms using Python, and if there are any available Python libraries out there that could manipulate image matrices to do derivation over time.